# Llenar Dataframe en función de un tiempo de duración en Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente conjunto de datos:

```
Bitácora    Dia Inicio  Hora Inicio  Duración de Recorrido
----------------------------------------------------------
A22FRG4         1        16:00:00             40
BW45345         1        04:00:00             12
EVRT234         2        22:00:00              4
WD47832         2        12:00:00              3
4CV45466        3        07:00:00             10
```

Lo que se requiero es una función en Python que me genere un nuevo Dataframe donde las filas son las horas y las columnas son los días. Para el registro de datos en este nuevo Dataframe se toma la Duración de Recorrido de la Bitácora partiendo desde el Día de Inicio y Hora de Inicio; por ejemplo, la Bitácora A22FRG4 tiene un tiempo de duración de 40 horas y su Hora de Inicio fue a las 16 horas del Día 1, entonces está bitácora se debe contar 40 veces, partiendo la suma desde la hora 16 y terminando el conteo (40) al 3er dia a las 6 horas. A este nuevo Dataframe se le debe sumar la duración de las otras Bitácoras con la misma lógica del ejemplo anterior, partiendo del Dia y su Hora de Inicio, como es el caso de la 2da Bitácora (BW45345) que coincide su cierre de duración justo a las 16 horas con el inicio de la 1era Bitácora A22FRG4, dando como resultado la presencia de 2 Bitácoras a las 16 horas.

El resultado que requiero seria lo siguiente:

```
Hora/Día    1   2   3
---------------------
0           0   2   2
1           0   2   2
2           0   1   1
3           0   1   1
4           1   1   1
5           1   1   1
6           1   1   1
7           1   1   2
8           1   1   1
9           1   1   1
10          1   1   1
11          1   1   1
12          1   2   1
13          1   2   1
14          1   2   1
15          1   2   1
16          2   1   1
17          1   1   
18          1   1   
19          1   1   
20          1   1   
21          1   1   
22          1   2   
23          1   2
```

Les reseño un ejemplo de función que estoy desarrollando la lógica pero aún no consigo el objetivo:

```
def cTrabajo(row):
    for i in set(df.index):
        result1 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df["DURACION RECORRIDO"])] #Repetir Indices
        result2 = df["HORA INICIO"] + 1 #Sumar 1 a cada Hora Inicio
        if int(row["nHInicio"]) > 23:
            result3 = df["HORA INICIO"] + 1
            if int(row["nDInicio"]) > 30:
                result4 = df["DIA INICIO"] + 1
    return result3, result4
```

Quizás me estoy complicando un poco por no saber alguna otra función o atributo en pandas que me ayude a facilitar lo que deseo.

Comment: Una cosa no tengo del todo clara. Si la bitácora 2 durase en vez de 12 horas 11 horas y 59 minutos y 29 segundos, terminaría a las 15:59:59 por lo que en la hora 16:00 el contador sería 1. Si dura un segundo más ¿el contador ya es 2? ¿Porque se solapan tan solo un segundo? Dicho de otro modo. La hora de finalización no sería más bien la hora a la que "ya no está"? En ese caso el contador de las 16:00 valdría 1. En la hora de 16:00 a 17:00 sólo está en marcha la bitácora 1 (la 2 termina justo a las 16:00, podríamos decir que un infinitésimo antes)

Comment: Hola, aclaro; para este ejemplo no es determinante los minutos ni segundos (Así tenga 59 minutos con 59 segundos), seria solo tomar en cuenta la hora, en la cual en función a la duración del recorrido se debe adicionar 1. Ej: Hora de Inicio 4 horas, duración de recorrido 10 horas, debe repetirse cada bitácora hasta las 14 horas, donde la hora de inicio sea 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14. Otro punto es que se tiene tomar en cuenta es que si supera las 24 horas, se debe empezar sumar el dia siguiente una vez registrado las 24 horas del día anterior.

Comment: Si, pero mi comentario iba en la línea de que si la bitácora 2 dura 12h y comienza a las 4:00, terminaría _exactamente_ a las 16:00. Por tanto no estaría actva durante la hora 16:00 a 17:00. En esa hora estaría activa sólo la bitácora 1. Por tanto el contador de la hora 16 debería ser 1 y no 2. A menos que cuentes que ambas se solaparon durante un instante, justo a las 16:00. El solapamiento tendría de hecho longitud cero, pues una acaba a las 16:00 mientras otra empieza a las 16:00. Por eso no veo sentido a dar valor 2 a ese contador

Comment: En el ejemplo que has puesto en el comentario: hora de inicio 4, duración 10, las horas de inicio deberían ser 4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12 y 13. La hora 14 ya no estaría pues de lo contrario la duración sería de 11 horas y no 10

Comment: Ah entiendo, si, tienes razón, es la lógica tal como comentas. Si tienes alguna idea me sería de ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Complementando lo anterior, la logica que busco seria: Lógica:
`Sumar unidad a hora de inicio de acuerdo a la hora de duración de dicha bitácora
nHora Inicio = Hora Inicio + 1
Si la Hora Inicio supera las 23 horas, se debe adicionar un día a la Fecha de Inicio (La hora de inicio debe empezar en cero en el día siguiente)
Si Hora Inicio > 23
nFecha Inicio = Fecha Inicio + 1
Si Día Inicio > 30
nMes Inicio = Mes Inicio + 1`